# currency ticker without white space

Tags: jquery, html, css, currency, ticker

I want to create a currency ticker.A query retrieves the values from yahoo Finance API and display them as a text.The main issue is the white space at the end of the text.The marquee script [marquee plugin](http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin#examples) solves the gap issue. The setInterval disrupts the moving text because it starts from the beginning.

```js
     $(document).ready(function() {
       //StockPriceTicker();
       setInterval(StockPriceTicker, 5000);
     });

     function StockPriceTicker() {
       var Symbol = "",
         CompName = "",
         Price = "",
         ChnageInPrice = "",
         PercentChnageInPrice = "";
       var CNames = "^FTSE,HSBA.L,SL.L,BATS.L,BLND.L,FLG.L,RBS.L,RMG.L,VOD.L";
       var flickerAPI = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22" + CNames + "%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys";
       var StockTickerHTML = "";

       var StockTickerXML = $.get(flickerAPI, function(xml) {
         $(xml).find("quote").each(function() {
           Symbol = $(this).attr("symbol");
           $(this).find("Name").each(function() {
             CompName = $(this).text();
           });
           $(this).find("LastTradePriceOnly").each(function() {
             Price = $(this).text();
           });
           $(this).find("Change").each(function() {
             ChnageInPrice = $(this).text();
           });
           $(this).find("PercentChange").each(function() {
             PercentChnageInPrice = $(this).text();
           });

           StockTickerHTML += "<span>" + CompName + " " + Price + "</span>";
         });

         $(".marquee div").html(StockTickerHTML);
         //$("#dvStockTicker").jStockTicker({interval: 30, speed: 2});
       });
     }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}
.marquee {
  height: 25px;
  width: 420px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.marquee div {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}
.marquee span {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marquee">
  <div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is difficult without something that actually runs, though the one thing I  immediately react on is the `.marquee span { float: left; width: 50%; }`. Remove the  `width: 50%` or  changing it to `.marquee span { display: inline-block; }` might solve your problem, as doing this will make the `span` adjust to its content

Comment: I know i tried a lot with no luck.I hope someone can help.

Comment: Could you let me know what is not working with the answer a gave, so I will be able to adjust and you to accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you gave the `span` a fixed width, and if the text is smaller it will have a big white empty space in the end of each, so by adjusting the `.marquee span` rule like this solve that issue

```
.marquee span {
    display: inline-block;
}
.marquee span ~ span::before {
    content:'|';
    color: red;
    padding: 0 5px
}
```

The text interruption is caused by the fixed width on the `.marquee div`, so I made some adjustments to that one too

```
.marquee div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;          /*  start from right, can be removed  */
    animation: marquee 25s linear 2s infinite;
}
```

Sample snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            //StockPriceTicker();
            setInterval(StockPriceTicker , 1000);
        });
  
        function StockPriceTicker() {
            var Symbol = "", CompName = "", Price = "", ChnageInPrice = "", PercentChnageInPrice = ""; 
            var CNames = "^FTSE,HSBA.L,SL.L,BATS.L,BLND.L,FLG.L,RBS.L,RMG.L,VOD.L";
            var flickerAPI = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22" + CNames + "%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys";
            var StockTickerHTML = "";
            
            var StockTickerXML = $.get(flickerAPI, function(xml) {
                $(xml).find("quote").each(function () {
                    Symbol = $(this).attr("symbol");
                    $(this).find("Name").each(function () {
                        CompName = $(this).text();
                    });
                    $(this).find("LastTradePriceOnly").each(function () {
                        Price = $(this).text();
                    });
                    $(this).find("Change").each(function () {
                        ChnageInPrice = $(this).text();
                    });
                    $(this).find("PercentChange").each(function () {
                        PercentChnageInPrice = $(this).text();
                    });
                    
                    StockTickerHTML += "<span>"+CompName+" "+Price+"</span>";
                });
   
                $(".marquee div").html(StockTickerHTML);
                //$("#dvStockTicker").jStockTicker({interval: 30, speed: 2});
            });
        }
```

```css
body { margin: 20px; }

.marquee {
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px green solid;
}

.marquee span {
    display: inline-block;
}
.marquee span ~ span::before {
    content:'*';
    padding: 0 25px;
}

.marquee div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    animation: marquee 12s linear 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
    100% { transform: translate( -100%, 0); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marquee">
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Update based on comment

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            //StockPriceTicker();
            setInterval(StockPriceTicker , 5000);
        });
  
        function StockPriceTicker() {
            var Symbol = "", CompName = "", Price = "", ChnageInPrice = "", PercentChnageInPrice = ""; 
            var CNames = "^FTSE,HSBA.L,SL.L,BATS.L,BLND.L,FLG.L,RBS.L,RMG.L,VOD.L";
            var flickerAPI = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22" + CNames + "%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys";
            var StockTickerHTML = "";
            
            var StockTickerXML = $.get(flickerAPI, function(xml) {
                $(xml).find("quote").each(function () {
                    Symbol = $(this).attr("symbol");
                    $(this).find("Name").each(function () {
                        CompName = $(this).text();
                    });
                    $(this).find("LastTradePriceOnly").each(function () {
                        Price = $(this).text();
                    });
                    $(this).find("Change").each(function () {
                        ChnageInPrice = $(this).text();
                    });
                    $(this).find("PercentChange").each(function () {
                        PercentChnageInPrice = $(this).text();
                    });
                    
                    StockTickerHTML += "<span>"+CompName+" "+Price+"</span>";
                });
   
                $(".marquee div").html(StockTickerHTML);
                //$("#dvStockTicker").jStockTicker({interval: 30, speed: 2});
            });
        }
```

```css
body { margin: 20px 0; }

.marquee {
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px green solid;
}
.marquee span {
    display: inline-block;
    background: lightgray;
}
.marquee span ~ span::before {
    content:'|';
    color: red;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
.marquee div {
    display: inline-block;
    animation: marquee 6s linear 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
    100% { transform: translate( calc(-100% + 100vw), 0); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marquee">
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok as you can notice something interrupts the smooth scrolling of the text.

Comment: @MariosNikolaou Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for your help, if you notice at the end of the text it has space ,how can i remove it?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou Added a 2:nd sample, does that one work as expected?

Comment: Marquee width should be 100%, i tested it and it's too slow

Comment: @MariosNikolaou Well, in your question the width was set to 420px. The speed you control with the animation time, `animation: marquee 25s linear 2s infinite;` .... I updated my 2:nd sample, full width and faster.

Comment: Check the full page from snippet. The moving breaks and starts from the beginning.

Comment: @MariosNikolaou I did, so what does not work when runned like that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134252/discussion-between-marios-nikolaou-and-lgson).